# Creating an ArrayList from SQLite DB is very slow

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, arraylist

Alright, so I'm trying to create a little and lightweight `ArrayList` from my SQLite DB.

Here's the code:

```
public ArrayList<Album> getAlbums()
{
    Cursor cursor = null;
    Cursor cursor2 = null;
    try{
        Log.d(Global.TAG, "STARTING");
        ArrayList<Album> albums = new ArrayList<Album>();
        Album album = new Album();
        db = getOpenDatabase(DBADS);
        String albumQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +albumsTableName + " ORDER BY " +albumIsMain + " DESC"; 
        cursor = db.rawQuery(albumQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Log.d(Global.TAG, "IN LOOP");
                album = new Album();
                album.id = cursor.getInt(0);
                album.albumName = cursor.getString(1);
                album.passcode = cursor.getString(2);
                album.isMainAlbum = cursor.getInt(3) == 1 ? true : false;
                albumQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + picturesTableName+" WHERE "+ pictureAlbumId +"="+album.id;
                cursor2 = db.rawQuery(albumQuery, null);
                cursor2.moveToFirst();
                album.photosCount = cursor2.getInt(0);
                cursor2.close();

                albums.add(album);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d(Global.TAG, "RETURNING");
        return albums;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
        }
        if(cursor2 != null){
            cursor2.close();
        }
        if(cursor3 != null){
            cursor3.close();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

The following code executes in like 8 seconds for only 6 items total! This is just exteremly slow.
There are not like 1000 rows here, but only 6.
After some debugging, I see that if I remove the other second inner cursor, it becomes very fast.

What could be the reason for that?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Save the result of first select statement in a list. Then pass them simultaneously to second select call. Rightnow you are making a lot of db calls

Comment: I don't really understand, could you please provide any further explanation or an example?

Comment: See the count operation takes a lot of time. So, make a list of albumtIds in first do while loop. Then, instead of album id you can pass all the album Ids together (outside do-while loop) : SELECT albumId FROM " + picturesTableName+" WHERE "+ pictureAlbumId +"in ("+albumIdList + ")";................. Now you need to loop over the result and count how many times a particular album Id is returned. That would require more java coding but will reduce db calls.

Comment: I've tried to implement your idea, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/d4VUq3TP but I'm getting an error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: in the associated PasteBin, I forgot to put a whitespace before the "IN" keyword, I fixed it in my original code, but I'm still getting the same error.